# Angular 9, ngx-datatable show button on mouseover

Tags: angular, typescript, ngx-datatable

I am trying to show link on mouse over of corresponding cell of ngx-datatable but instead it is showing the link on all the rows of that particular column, here is the code I am doing:

```
<ngx-datatable
        class="material ml-0 mr-0"
        [rows]="users"
        [columnMode]="'flex'"
        [headerHeight]="50"
        [footerHeight]="50"
        [limit]="10"
        [rowHeight]="'auto'">
        <ngx-datatable-column name="User Name" [flexGrow]="1">
            <ng-template let-row="row" ngx-datatable-cell-template>
            {{ row?.userName }}
            </ng-template>
        </ngx-datatable-column>
        <ngx-datatable-column name="Role" [flexGrow]="1">
            <ng-template let-row="row" let-rowIndex="rowIndex" ngx-datatable-cell-template let-value="value">
                <div (mouseenter)="showRoleOpt(rowIndex,true, $event)" (mouseleave)="showRoleOpt(rowIndex,false, $event)">{{ row?.role }} <a *ngIf="showRoleOptions">Change</a></div>
            </ng-template>
        </ngx-datatable-column>
        <ngx-datatable-column name="First Name" [flexGrow]="1">
            <ng-template let-row="row" ngx-datatable-cell-template>
                {{ row?.firstName }}
            </ng-template>
        </ngx-datatable-column>
        <ngx-datatable-column name="Last Name" [flexGrow]="1">
            <ng-template let-row="row" ngx-datatable-cell-template>
                {{ row?.lastName }}
            </ng-template>
        </ngx-datatable-column>
        <ngx-datatable-column name="Email" [flexGrow]="1">
            <ng-template let-row="row" ngx-datatable-cell-template>
                {{ row?.email }}
            </ng-template>
        </ngx-datatable-column>
        <ngx-datatable-column name="Phone Number" [flexGrow]="1">
            <ng-template let-row="row" ngx-datatable-cell-template>
                {{ row?.phoneNumber }}
            </ng-template>
        </ngx-datatable-column>
        <ngx-datatable-column name="Actions" [flexGrow]="1">
            <ng-template let-row="row" ngx-datatable-cell-template>
            <button mat-icon-button mat-sm-button color="primary" class="mr-1" (click)="openPopUp(row)"><mat-icon>edit</mat-icon></button>
            <button mat-icon-button mat-sm-button color="warn" (click)="deleteItem(row)"><mat-icon>delete</mat-icon></button>
            </ng-template>
        </ngx-datatable-column>
</ngx-datatable>
```

TS code:

```
showRoleOpt(row, opt: boolean, $event) {
    console.log($event.target);
    this.showRoleOptions = opt;
  }
```

I tried to put some id to div, looking to check the event if there is anything I can do with. But not getting any clue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason behind this behavior is that you are using same `flag` for all `rows`, so you can have flag on each row:

```
<ng-template let-row="row" let-rowIndex="rowIndex" ngx-datatable-cell-template let-value="value">
                <div (mouseenter)="showRoleOpt(row,true, $event)" (mouseleave)="showRoleOpt(row,false, $event)">{{ row?.role }} <a *ngIf="row.showRoleOptions">Change</a></div>
</ng-template>
```

ts:

```
showRoleOpt(row:any, opt: boolean, $event) {
    console.log($event.target);
    row.showRoleOptions = opt;
}
```

Comment: ERROR TypeError: Cannot create property 'showRoleOptions' on number '0' after adding rrow.showRoleOptions = opt;

Comment: export class ManageusersComponent implements OnInit {
  users;
  showRoleOptions;
  constructor(private userService: UserService, private router: Router) { }
showRoleOptions is just a value.

Comment: also change the variable in template from rowIndex to row, which you are passing in the method, please see the changes in html from my answer

Comment: How did you came to know that I have to add row. in the function? It is Angular where I am legging or just a specific property for ngx-datatable which I am not aware of

Comment: it is simple logic, if you use same variable for each row, then on mouseover on one row will be applied on all rows, so its clear that we need a variable for each row(or object)

Comment: Please provide fiddle validating your answer.